# Python 3.3 I/O with input?

Tags: python, input, python-3.x, io

I'm learning Python 3 and I'm trying to use the I/O function, so I created a program that goes like this:

```
class IOpractice:
    print("Welcome to IOpractice.")
    text = input("Text: ")
    fileName = input("Filename: ")
    outFile = open(fileName, 'wt')
    outFile.write(text)
    outFile.close()
    print('...\nFile Saved')
    print('\n Press enter to load a file.')
    input()
    fileLoad = input("Filename: ")
    inFile = open(fileLoad, 'rt')
    inFile.read()
    input()
    print("Thanks for playing.")
```

For some reason, when I use the program, it works until I try and load the file, at which point it returns nothing at all, just a blank.

Can someone help by telling me what's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance, Paul.

Comment: You don't need the `class IOpractice:` line here. In fact, it makes your code somewhat confusing to read to other Python programmers, since you don't define any real class members. Python is not Java, you don't *have* to define a class.

Comment: If you remove the `class` line and remove the indentation, your code will run just the same.

Comment: For *other* types of programs, however, not using a class when all you wanted to do was run some top-level code *will* make a difference as you are then properly defining globals, not class attributes.

Comment: Your second-to-last line has `input()` - seems unnecessary...

Answer (score 1):

Where is:

```
print(inFile.read())
```

?

Comment: There's probably a more constructive way of saying this. Otherwise true.

Comment: Oh - I - thanks for answering. It's kind of obvious now that I see it but I was genuinely confused. Sorry for asking a dumb question :)